# can I configure tmux with a single key shortcut for ":kill-session"?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I'm using tmux in an application (I have a script that automatically loads scripts in each split) and I'm wondering if there's a way to configure a single shortcut like `ctrl-q` (I realize that `ctrl-c` will just quit whatever script is running in the active pane of tmux) to quit the whole application instead of typing `ctrl-b` and then type `:kill-session`?

It may be like binding `:kill-session` to the actual prefix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>:

```
bind -n C-q kill-session
```

This is a tmux command (i.e for `.tmux.conf` or to be typed after <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>). In a shell you can pass it to tmux by invoking:

```
tmux bind -n C-q kill-session
```

For sole <kbd>q</kbd> (a truly single-key shortcut) use `q` instead of `C-q`.